# ¿Cómo validar si una hora esta en un rango de horas para registrarlo como asistencia en php?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Estoy desarrollando un sistema web donde debo registrar las asistencias pero debo validar la hora de registro del empleado y este debe determinar si está en el rango de la hora de registros.

Supongamos que en mí base de datos tengo la tabla horario en la cual sus atributos son los siguientes junto a sus registros, en este caso puede variar ya que algunos trabajadores tienen más horas de entrada que otros.

- HorasEntrada  =  08:30:00,12:00:00,15:00:00
- HorasSalida   =  11:00:00,14:00:00,16:00:00

Y otra tabla llamada asistencias donde registro las horas de llegada y de salida del empleado.
Sus atributos son:

- idempleado  : almacena el idempleado
- fechaRegistro  : la hora que registro su asistencia
- estatus : registrao si la asistencia tuvo retardo,no registro o puntal

Con base a esos datos cuando el empleado llega al establecimiento, debe registrar sus asistencia para eso obtengo los datos de la tabla donde están los horarios de entrada y salida. Ejemplo si el empleado llega y hace su registro a las 08:00:00 entonces debo recorrer mi array de horas de entradas, y ver  que hora esta más próximo.

Mi array de ejemplo sería este: 08:30:00,12:00:00,15:00:00 (cabe mencionar que los horarios son diferentes por empleado o sea será dinámico)

Entonces el problema me surgue cuando deseo saber la hora de registro sea próximo a del array y así verificar si llegó a tiempo o tuvo un retardo.

Comment: porque dices que deberías recorrer un array de horario de entrada, un empleado no tiene una hora de entrada fija para un día?

Comment: Porque hay empleados que salen a otros lugares y al llegar deben registrarse de nuevo por eso tienen muchas horas de entrada con sus salidas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero creo que necesitaras modificar un poco tu esquema de DB.

A mi parecer la data deberia de tener esta estructura:
[image: esquema de BD]

Para determinar si una fecha esta en el rango correcto (Pseudocodigo):

- fechaRegistro >= fechaHoraEntrada
- fechaRegistro <= fechaHoraSalida
- Si 1 y 2 se cumplen esta en el rango

El codigo podria ser algo asi:

```
<?php
    //Data obtenida de la BD
    $duracion_turno_horas = 8;
    $hora_entrada_empleado = 8;
    $minutos_entrada_empleado = 30;
    $registro_asistencia = date_create('2020-01-07 08:30:00');
    //Data obtenida de la BD

    // Tomamos la fecha de hoy, o podriamos iniciar la fecha en el mismo dia que el registro fue generado
    $fecha_entrada = date_create('2020-01-07'); 
    // Establecemos la hora y minutos
    date_time_set($fecha_entrada, $hora_entrada_empleado, $minutos_entrada_empleado);
    echo 'Empleado deberia de entrar:'.date_format($fecha_entrada, 'Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
    //Sumaos la duracion de su turno para calcular la hora de salida
    $fecha_salida = date_add(clone $fecha_entrada, date_interval_create_from_date_string($duracion_turno_horas." hours")); 
    echo 'Empleado deberia de salir:'.date_format($fecha_salida, 'Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
    $esta_en_rango = $fecha_entrada <= $registro_asistencia && $fecha_salida >= $registro_asistencia;
    $esta_en_rango_string = $esta_en_rango ? 'true' : 'false';
    echo "Esta en rango? - {$esta_en_rango_string}"; // false


?>
```

Si necesitas comparar multiple rangos simplemente puede colocar la logica en bucle `for`

Espero esto te funcione como una base para el problema que necesitas solucionar

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
$fecha_actual = date("d-m-Y H:i");
//sumo una hora
echo date("d-m-Y H:i",strtotime($fecha_actual."+ 1 hour")); 
//resto una hora
echo date("d-m-Y H:i",strtotime($fecha_actual."- 1 hour"));
```